# How to set the 'left' property of my div using css3 calc?

Tags: css

I am trying to set the left property of a div in an exact location depending on the width of its parent.

Specifically I want the 'left' property to be its parent width - 350px.

I am trying to use css3's calc like this (left: calc(100% - 350px)) to no avail.  This probably is because 100% is looking at the left property instead of the parent's width...

Is this possible at all or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
<div id="login5" class="login">
    <h3>Login</h3>

    // code 

</div>
```

Then in my css:

```
#login5 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 260px;
    left: calc(100% - 350px);
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6);
    padding: 20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It should work (on Chrome/Safari/Firefox/IE9+): http://jsfiddle.net/GXbJT/

According to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc), Opera doesn't support it. And vendor-specific prefix is still required for WebKit-based browsers:

```css
left:-webkit-calc(100% - 350px);
left:-moz-calc(100% - 350px);
left:calc(100% - 350px);
```

Answer (score 1):

Test with:

```
transform: translateX(25px);
```

and you move your tag to the right, or

```
transform: translateX(-25px);
```

and you move to the left.

Answer (score -3):

I changed the left property to width, just check it.

```
 #login5 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 260px;
    width: calc(100% - 350px);
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6);
    padding: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean??  I am trying to set the LEFT property - not the width twice????

Comment: ok, check it out this link. it will help you to solve your problem. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc