# Two div equally spaced form center above another div

Tags: html, css, web

I need to have two divs with images equally spaced from the center of the page, one on the left and another one on the right, above central div.

I have tried to make an example in the following picture:

[image: blue divs need to be equally spaced from center]

the main page div (flowers) is 1024 pixel, and the two right/left blue divs need to stay in the same position...
I am not that CSS expert ...how can I achieve this behaviour?

my CSS code so far:

```
.overlay-left{
background-color: transparent !important;
 background-image: url("/images/background-left.png");
 background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 100vw;
position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    //left: calc(-60vw + 50%);
    left: calc(-50% + 600px);
margin-left: -150px;
  z-index: 100;
}


.overlay-right{
background-color: transparent !important;
 background-image: url("/images/background-right.png");
 background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 100vw;
position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    //left: calc(+130vw - 50%);
    left: 1024px;
margin-left: 100px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: OK i will post my code

Comment: Do you want the divs (left and right) set to 0 from left and right or a little more?

Comment: I am using a fixed width of 1024 px for the main body. left and right divs are images with a width of 400 px ...idealy they need to be centered at 0 (so, from -200 to +200) px and 1024 px (so, from +800 to + 1224px), as in the mockup i posted....

Comment: I am fiddling with:

 left: calc(50vw -800px);
(should be half of the viewport width - 800 pixels....)
but doesn't work...

Comment: @Antonio You want it to be like the attached image?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is define a parent for your image *(here `#parent`)* and put image, and two other div[s] inside that parent.

**You can do this:**

```css
#parent{
 position:relative;
  
  }

#parent img{
max-width:94%;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  
}

#parent> div{
width:50px;
  height:300px;
  background:rgba(125,125,255,0.5);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
 
}
#right{
 right:0; 
}

#left{
left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/744081-background-wallpaper.jpg"/>  
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div id="left"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed the problem by using Calc.
I need to calculate half of the width of the page and then subtract or add a fixed number of pixels.
I Wa using Left with Calc with no luck, until I found this:

[How to set the 'left' property of my div using css3 calc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137986/how-to-set-the-left-property-of-my-div-using-css3-calc)

so basically I needed to use webkit-calc, moz-cal instead of simple "calc"

Now this is a snippet of working CSS:

```
.overlay-left{
background-color: transparent !important;
background-image: url("/images/background-left.png");
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 100vw;
position: absolute;
width: 400px;
left:-webkit-calc(100%/2 - 842px);
left:-moz-calc(100%/2 - 842px);
left:calc(100%/2 - 842px);
z-index: 100;
}
```