# How to center an overlay div to content area with outside images

Tags: css

I've added an overlay divs using absolute positioning, where the overlay divs are wider than the content divs, and I've included an image on the left of one content div and an image on the right of another as shown in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/781jzogv/). Over 1200px screen width the images are centered over the content div left and right borders. For screens less than 1380px wide the image on the right stays in the fixed position whilst the red box width reduces, and at a screen width of 1200px and below the image goes off screen and is hidden.

How can I replicate this behaviour for the image on the left, ie push it off screen as content width reduces instead of it moving into the content area? Some how the overlay div needs to preserved it's centered status over the content area.

My code is below and in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/781jzogv/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
img {max-width: 100%;}
html,body {height: 100%;width:100%;}
body {overflow-x: hidden;max-width: 100%;}
.main {max-width: 100%;overflow: hidden;}
section {z-index: 1;position: static;clear: both;}
section > div {z-index: 3;position: relative;}
.section-2 {
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 30px 0;
    position:relative;
}
.section-2 .container {
    text-align: left;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.section-2 .target-wrap {
    position:absolute;
    top:160px;
    width:100%;
}
.section-2 .target-right {
    width:1380px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:right;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.section-2 .target-left {
    width:1380px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.section-2 .target-right img, .section-2 .target-left img {
    width:200px;
}
</style>
```

```
<div>
  <section class="section-2">
    <div class="container">
        <p>The absolute positioned div with blue border has a fixed width of 1380px to position the image about centered over the red box right border for screen widths of 1380px and over</p>
        <p>For screens less than 1380px wide the image stays in the fixed position whilst the red box width reduces, and at a screen width of 1200px and below the image goes off screen and is hidden.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="target-wrap">
        <div class="target-right">
            <img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <section class="section-2">
    <div class="container">
        <p>How can the behaviour of the image on the right be replicated for this image on the left?</p>
        <p>At the moment the behaviour is the same for screen widths of 1200px and above, but below 1200px wide the image stays on screen and moves inside the red box.</p>
        <p>How can the CSS be modified to ensure that at below 1200px screen width this left image stays centered over the red box left border and moves off-screen to the left?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="target-wrap">
        <div class="target-left">
            <img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: I could add a media query to reset the .target-left left position below 1380px screen width; I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137986/how-to-set-the-left-property-of-my-div-using-css3-calc) using calc to set left position, but apparently calc doesn't work with opera. I'm trying to fix  the .target-wrap position relative to it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

I was over complicating the solution! All I needed to do was put the .target-left and .target-right inside their .container and set a negative left position for .target-left and a negative right position for .target-right, and remove target-wrap.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand your problem, but i am sure you can solve this using media query. Media query specifies what happens at certain viewport width. For example:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Learn more here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: I already know about media queries thank you, but I don't see how one would be applied to solve this particular issue. Your answer is not specific enough to help solve the issue.

Comment: For example, how would a media query allow the overlay div to extend beyond the viewport and remain centered over the content area?